# IPads and auto resizing / rescaling of websites

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am always a little confused when I design a website that is not fluid / responsive and then view that site on an IPad as to the differing results that I see.

I'm wondering how exactly the IPad resizes / scales websites?

One developer has told me in a discussion that if you say create a website that is 1200px wide then you don't need to worry as the IPad will scale this automatically.  By this scaling, I mean that the whole site will always be visible in terms of not needing to horizontally scroll.

Sometimes this tends to be the case but then you look at some pages of the same site and this is just not true.

It almost seems to be a bit random as to which pages display correctly and which don't and this can be very frustrating.

Based on the above, I guess taking this a bit more extreme I would expect a 4000px website to display horizontally on an IPad even though the content would be extremely small and would require zooming in to make it legible.  Would that be a correct assumption?

There also appears to be some automatic zooming on sites when the orientation is changed and again this is very annoying.  Is there an explanation for this?

Lastly I have read a lot about solutions that disable the pinch.  This seems fine for the IPad but a lot trickier for the IPhone as the zoom is needed for pretty much all users in order to make the content legible. Is it possible to disable it for one device and not the other?

Thanks for all input.

Answer (score 3):

Whack

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = device-width">
```

in your HTML `<head>`. It tells the device not to scale it down.

You could use PHP to determine the device and toggle that line of code where necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure if I made myself clear but I do not ever want a user to have to horizontally scroll.

What I am looking for is a way to always force the IPad to fit the design horizontally regardless of the size of the website or the orientation of the IPad.

Comment: oh, ok... in that case, leave the meta tag out - it should behave as you desire, by default.

Comment: Yes that is what my whole post is in regards too.  However this does not always seem to be the case. I was wondering why this might be.  Do you think it is a case of some rogue CSS that is forcing the IPad to have to provide some horizontal scrolling?  If it always resizes then I'm not sure how this could possibly be?